# Неправильное отображение строки

Tags: java, json, строки, коллекции

Написал код, который, по-хорошему, должен отображать подобие JSON в строку.
Не работает, выдает просто "[]".

**Код класса:**

```
package com.example;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class SimpleJSON extends Thread {
    private Collection<Object> collection;
    public void run(){
    System.out.print(JSONdb());
    }
    public String JSONdb() {
        try {
            collection = new ArrayList<Object>();
            collection.add(new IDdb(new String[]{"ggg", "fdf"}));
            collection.add(new GPSdb(new String[]{"ggg", "fdf"}));
            collection.add(new Distancedb(new String[]{"ggg", "fdf"}));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return String.valueOf(collection);
    }
}

class IDdb {
    private String[] iddb;
    IDdb(String[] iddb) {
        this.iddb = iddb;
    }
}

class GPSdb {
    private String[] gpsdb;
    GPSdb(String[] gpsdb) {
        this.gpsdb = gpsdb;
    }
}

class Distancedb {
    private String[] distdb;
    Distancedb(String[] distdb) {
        this.distdb = distdb;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для классов нужно переопределить `toString()` и попробовать `return collection.toString()` в методе `public String JSONdb()`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте возвращать не `String.valueOf(collection)`

а

```
Arrays.toString(collection.toArray(new Object[collection.size()]));
```

Comment: ошибка "cannot resolve method".

Comment: @DenShDen, а если так?..

Comment: опять выдает просто [].